# How to debug Android's built-in browser for my website?

Tags: android, debugging, browser, cross-browser

My website works well on Google Chrome 42 and Mozilla Firefox 47 on Android, but doesn't work with Android's built-in browser (also with Opera Mini 17), how can I know which part of `javascript` that makes my site not running correctly?

**Note**: I didn't ask for debugging on Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox mobile, but for Android's built-in browser or with Opera Mini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilise a great tool called [Weinre](https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/) for this purpose :)

**What does it do?**

It allows you to debug website running on your phone from your desktop, think of it as a developer tool for your mobile web browser.

**How do I set it up?**

First install npm, if you're on Windows, follow this [link](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows) npm on Windows
Run cmd as admin, then install weinre with the following command:

```
npm -g install weinre
```

Now start the weinre server:

```
weinre --httpPort 8081 --boundHost -all-

--httpPort specifies the port to run the HTTP server on, default is 8080.
--boundHost specifies the ip address to bind the server to. Default is localhost, but for convenience make it bind to all ip addresses.
```

Now go to http://localhost:8081/, you will see your Weinre running nice and fresh.